# display database values in all page in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

i create one login.jsp..after login show teleD.jsp.in teleD.jsp...

```
    <%@include file="header.jsp" %>

    <%@include file="updatebtn.jsp" %>
```

in header.jsp...include connection.jsp file which have oracle connection...
in heaader.jsp i set and get attributes and display database employee data in table...

In updatebtn, i made 4 buttons,after clicking on button i have to display header.jsp and also with database value...

so i am creating updateinfo.jsp page after clicking on updatebtn.jsp....and include on that page header.jsp and  updateinfo.jsp.....but that time In header.jsp show null value....

plz tell me how to show database value in all page

Comment: Use an MVC framework such as Stripes or Spring MVC, and stop putting Java code in JSPs. They should only be used to generate markup from beans stored in request attributes.

Comment: This is a bad design. I guess you're coming from php or some kind of language where you can put all your server code in your page. Well, Java has moved on to more sophisticated technologies to avoid this kind of approach. It will be better use a MVC framework like JSF, Spring, Struts or other. Also, you should read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/1065197

Comment: As guessing you are a beginner use Struts 2.0 mvc approach to accomplish this task, it will be much more convenient you to understand. Don't use database related logic in your jsps.